# What should I do if I chose a wrong experimental result for conclusions in academic paper?

Tags: graduate-school

I'm a graduate student who has recently submitted my paper to an academic conference.
All I have to do now is to wait for a few more days for the result.

I intended to show that even with small penalty the significant speedup could be achieved by my computer architecture and neural network design.
There were about a dozen experimental setups with differing degree of penalty.
I explained in abstract, experimental results and even in conclusion that even with the penalty limited below a%, the speedup of b times could be achieved.

But it turned out that I kind of cherrypicked and mixed the penalty and the experimental result.
The difference in neither penalty nor speedup is huge. The penalty selected was right next in the table to the penalty which should've been considered. Such as (a * 1.2)% instead of a%
And the speedup differs about 20% too.

So either the penalty limit should be raised by 20% or the resulting speedup should be decreased by 20% in the conclusion of my paper.
It seems like a huge speedup even with 20% deduction as it is above 1.3x

But I'm scared that reviewers will reject my paper for that mistake, suspecting me of being unethical such as faking or fabricating the result.
If the reviewers give me chance to explain, I can explain the mistake thoroughly as penalty-speedup correlation is even shown in the graph.
But the conference has no rebuttal period. They only allow me to edit between the acceptance and the camera-ready submission.

If the error is that much easy to spot, and even the corrected result seems promising, should I stop worrying about the effect of this error on the possibility of being accepted?

Comment: As a researcher you have to own your work and take responsibility. There is no such thing as "it turned out I kind of cherry picked...". We all make mistakes. But in order to avoid repeating them don't make it sound like a random accident that was discovered after the fact when it was a part of your active decision making process. (Just a minor suggestion about how you use words here.)

Answer (score 1):

If only for honesty's sake, you should send a corrected version to the committee and explain your mixup.

Put yourself into the shoes of the hapless graduate student who tries to replicate your results in a few years as starting point of own research, only to find out nothing matches up.